# SAN Boot CHAP'd iSCSI Target?

Tags: storage, ubuntu-10.04, storage-area-network, iscsi

I have a few computers on my network that boot via iSCSI (due to dead HDDs) using chainloaded iPXE over DHCP.  I wanted to enable CHAP for my iSCSI target to increase security (and learn).  However, iPXE does not appear to support CHAP...

**Is it possible to boot from iSCSI and use CHAP at the same time?**

Comment: I'm fairly sure the answer is NO because the only way to transmit the CHAP credentials would be over any insecure channel, defeating the purpose.

Comment: If you can't use CHAP, than what is the security model for SAN booting using iSCSI?

Comment: Normally you'd have an iSCSI HBA so you can configure the CHAP security on the card's firmware. iPXE to be iSCSI is an ugly hack IMHO.

Comment: If you post that as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use iPXE and CHAP at the same time.

You need to set iPXE options, either in script or through your DHCP server. The relevant options are (from http://ipxe.org/cfg):

```
**Authentication settings**
username     (string)    User name
password     (string)    Password
reverse-username     (string)    Reverse user name
reverse-password     (string)    Reverse password
```